# Does eta-expansion allocate an object?

Tags: scala, jvm, jvm-hotspot

When using scala functions on the hot path, we need to be careful not to create new functions willy-nilly because they each entail an allocation.  However, eta-expanded methods have the advantage that they have a fixed definition in the method, and we know that they're not closing over anything they don't already have in the method context.  Does scala still allocate a new object on each eta-expansion?

Comment: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/eta-expansion-internals-in-scala.html

Comment: Note that since that article was written, the compiler was completely refactored in 2012 (2.10), the code generation backend was completely thrown away and replaced (2015, 2.12), the representation of first-class functions was completely changed to how Java 8 does it (2015, 2.12), and the 2.12 release notes also explicitly mention optimizations for inlining of first-class functions into higher-order functions.

Comment: I did a little informal exploration in both 2.11 and 2.12 using `:javap` in the REPL and also using tests like `(x _) eq (x _)` and couldn't find any cases where the object allocation doesn't happen. But, maybe I didn't try exactly the right code with exactly the right optimizer settings in 2.12, I don't know. And god knows what HotSpot does with it. But in any case, it appears the normal answer is that yes, eta-expansion allocates.